# Character of principal series representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, reductive-groups

I am looking for an explicit form of the character of principal series representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

At the moment I am particularly interested in the case $n=2$.

A reference would be most helpful.